# jquery problem with selector

Tags: jquery

i have simple jquery code as below:

```
 $('.editImg').live('click', function (event) {
        var bb = $(this).closest("tr").find("label[title='lblAbonCodeMid']").text().trim();
     });
```

it works in all browsers except ie 8 and ie 9. what i am doing wrond
it says  Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: There should be no reason this doesn't work in IE. In any case you'll need to post the relevant HTML in order to be able to analyse the problem.

Comment: Wait, I'm wrong. See my answer.

Comment: i have test it without trim. it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is probably not supported in IE (as method of the `String` object (`text()` returns a string)). It is only part of ES5.

Try [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
$.trim($(this).closest("tr").find("label[title='lblAbonCodeMid']").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [**`$.trim()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) in jQuery.

```
 $('.editImg').live('click', function (event) {
    var bb = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find("label[title='lblAbonCodeMid']").text());
 });
```

> String.trim() is part of the
>   ECMAScript 5 standard.

Read [**trim**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

[**ECMAScript 5 compatibility table**](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

Comment: thanks for giving link to read about ECMAScript. it is new for me.thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `trim()` on `String`s in IE. Use `jQuery.trim()` instead:

```
var bb = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find("label[title='lblAbonCodeMid']").text());
```